# Is it thread-safe to write this?

Tags: asp.net

Can I write something like the following (in an assembly being used in an ASP.NET web page)?

```
public static string CurrentAuthenticatedUserFromHttpRequest
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["AuthUser"] == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return HttpContext.Current.Items["AuthUser"].ToString(); //set in "TryAuthenticate"
    }
}
```

It is going to be a static read-only property.  The value (to HttpContext.Current.Items["AuthUser"]) is set through a httphandler.

Just wondering on how this would perform during multiple requests.  Is the data going to be accurate when multiple users try to access the same property (in multiple requests), even when high volumes of requests come in?

Comment: HttpContext is per HTTP request, how are you going to share the data between users anyway?

Comment: Maybe I can mistake , but when user makes request to the server , after appdomain iscreated , then The HttpContext class is created , the class contains objects that are specific to the current application request, such as the HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects. The HttpRequest object contains information about the current request.

Comment: I should have asked in a better way.  Apologies. I wanted to have this property to always return current user info through out the current request.  I am not trying to share values among multiple requests.  We had a debate on using HttpContext.Items (which is not thread-safe) being using in a static property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is threadsafe. The static `HttpContext.Current` property differs per thread and contains the context for the request that the thread is currently handling.